# Best way to monitor Firebase Storage for changes

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-storage

I am building an app in Unity using Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Storage.  I need to add functionality in the client app that is triggered when a particular Storage directory is updated.  The update could happen from the Firebase console itself, not necessarily from the client app.

I know you can monitor for changes of a database node, but there doesn't seem to be a quick way to monitor for changes of a storage directory.  I could poll for changes, but it would be better to get realtime update.

Should I look into using Cloud Functions to update the database when the storage is updated so I can be notified in the client app?  Or perhaps use Cloud Messaging?  Please point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: You can write Cloud Storage triggers with Cloud Functions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing build into Cloud Storage for Firebase to inform client-side code.

The typical way to solve this is to write an update to the database whenever the file in storage is updated. That way you can keep an active listener on the database.

But sending an FCM message is also a valid option. Such a message is called a tickle, since it tickles the app to get it into action.

You could do either of those from Cloud Functions, or from within the application code itself. But if you also want to capture updates from the Firebase console, Cloud Functions is really your only option.

Comment: Both of these solutions involve Cloud Functions, correct?  I can't just have the client app update the database because I need it to know about changes that were made directly in the console as well.

Comment: Nope. Though you could use Cloud Functions to detect the storage write and update the database, you can also do it in the app directly. But it definitely requires some code from you, nothing is done automatically for it. I added some more info to my answer.